# use WSO2 esb with Rest web services running on Tomcat

Tags: rest, tomcat, wso2, esb, wso2-esb

i'm very new to ESB.
i want to use WSO2 ESB with java rest web services which are running on tomcat application server.  all the communications are done using JSON.
 please help..

Answer (score 0):

here is a good tutorial on RESTful integration with WSO2 ESB

http://wso2.com/library/articles/2013/12/restful-integration-with-wso2-esb/

and extra details on JSON support

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB480/JSON+Support